# What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1+ 1/2 + 1/3 +\dots +1/n$. What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1- 1/2 + 1/3 +\dots +1/(2n-1)-1/(2n)?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1+ 1/2 + 1/3 +\dots +1/n$. What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1- 1/2 + 1/3 +\dots +1/(2n-1)-1/(2n)?$

I feel like $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1+ 1/2 + 1/3 +\dots +1/n$ should be equal with 2, but I'm not sure.
Any help is hugely appreciated, because I've never done such exercises before and I couldn't find how to approach them.

Comment: Harmonic series diverges

Comment: The first is $\infty$, and the second is $\ln 2$.

Comment: And the second is the Newton-Mercator expansion of $\ln 2$.

Comment: Thank you. How can I prove the limit of the second one is ln 2?